# "Char cannot be dereferenced" error

Tags: java, char, dereference

I'm trying to use the char method `isLetter()`, which is supposed to return boolean value corresponding to whether the character is a letter. But when I call the method, I get an error stating that "char cannot be dereferenced." I don't know what it means to dereference a char or how to fix the error. the statement in question is:

```
if (ch.isLetter()) 
{
....
....
}
```

Any help? What does it mean to dereference a char and how do I avoid doing so?

Comment: Don't try to call methods on primitives.  How about Character.isLetter(ch);

Answer (score 26):

The type char is a primitive -- not an object -- so it cannot be dereferenced

Dereferencing is the process of accessing the value referred to by a reference. Since a char is already a value (not a reference), it can not be dereferenced.

use `Character` class:

```
if(Character.isLetter(c)) {
```

Comment: +1 - though it should also be noted that the `.` in `Character.isLetter(c)` denotes the use of a static method of `Character`.

Answer (score 2):

A `char` doesn't have any methods - it's a Java [primitive](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). You're looking for the [Character](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter%28char%29) wrapper class.

The usage would be:

```
if(Character.isLetter(ch)) { //... }
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess `ch` is a declared as `char`. Since `char` is a primitive data type and not and object, you can't call any methof from it. You should use `Character.isLetter(ch)`.

Answer (score -1):

If `Character.isLetter(ch)` looks a bit wordy/ugly you can use a static import.

```
import static java.lang.Character.*;


if(isLetter(ch)) {

} else if(isDigit(ch)) {

}
```